# nginx RTMP vs MPEG-TS

Tags: nginx, rtmp, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to figure our what's the best method to receive **live** streaming video at a server, and making it available back to the client.
I noticed two modules for nginx:

- https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module
- https://github.com/arut/nginx-ts-module

It looks like both modules support HLS for video streaming.
What is the difference then between the options?

Answer (score -1):

Apparently you can stream HLS/DASH with both but the nginx-ts-module has fewer features. You can setup both using docker and test which one suits your needs better. I'd almost always go with the simpler option.